# Extract Text Within a Long Varying String of Text

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

The problem I'm having is this. The data I pull adds information in a very inconvenient way. When I'm trying to isolate and extract a certain text within the string it becomes super complicated. I want to be able to extract "Ships in 1-2 business days" some of the strings are listed as "Ships 1-2 weeks" which also needs to be extracted if applicable.

The string in the cell is:

> [{"orderItemId":609507407,"lineItemKey":"1509870501993","sku":"SKU-111111","name":"Company
>   Product - NA / Ships in 1-2 business
>   days","imageUrl":"https://FAKEADDRESS.com/","weight":{"value":352.0,"units":"ounces","WeightUnits":1},"quantity":1,"unitPrice":1599.0,"taxAmount":null,"shippingAmount":null,"warehouseLocation":null,"options":[],"productId":30236912,"fulfillmentSku":null,"adjustment":false,"upc":"","createDate":"2018-11-03T20:20:42.247","modifyDate":"2018-11-03T20:20:42.247"}]

**Using =RIGHT(C5,LEN(C5)-FIND("Ships",C5,1)+1)** I'm able to find what I need, however everything after still remains. See below example.

> Ships in 1-2 business
>   days","imageUrl":"https://FAKEADDRESS.com/","weight":{"value":352.0,"units":"ounces","WeightUnits":1},"quantity":1,"unitPrice":1599.0,"taxAmount":null,"shippingAmount":null,"warehouseLocation":null,"options":[],"productId":30236912,"fulfillmentSku":null,"adjustment":false,"upc":"","createDate":"2018-11-03T20:20:42.247","modifyDate":"2018-11-03T20:20:42.247"}]

Essentially, I just want the formula to pull out the text "Ships in 1-2 business days" some of the strings will contain "Ships in 1-2 weeks" if it is not a 1-2 day shipping method, which I would like to extract as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formula you need. It's a variation of what you already have.

```
=LEFT(B12,FIND(CHAR(34),B12)-1)
```

Of course, B12 holds the formula you published. So, by replacing "B12" with your formula you get the result you want.

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(C5,LEN(C5)-FIND("Ships",C5,1)+1),FIND(CHAR(34),RIGHT(C5,LEN(C5)-FIND("Ships",C5,1)+1))-1)
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work. The result it gives me is just these values [{

Comment: Actually just kidding, that worked perfect. I found the formatting issue i did previously. Thanks so much!

Comment: That scared me! :-)

Comment: What does the char(34) represent? I would like to also get the product name under "Company Product - NA" as well as the "quantity":1 (just the number) as well but I'm not sure how to reverse engineer the formula.

Comment: Char(34) is a quotation mark. You might replace it with """

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. So if I were to try and extract the product and quantity, how would I go about that? Thanks for your help by the way! You're a life saver

Comment: I only save one life at a time - no follow-ups. But you should be able to do it with the tools you have: First find the beginning of the string you want using your own formula. Then find the end of the string in the string you extracted. Finally, merge the 2 formulas the way I demonstrated. In development, I entered your text in A12, your formula in B12 (changing C5 to become A12) and my formula in C12 (actually referring to B12).