# Extracting quantity (number) from long string of text

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

The problem I'm having is this. The data I pull adds information in a very inconvenient way. When I'm trying to isolate and extract a certain text within the string it becomes super complicated. I want to be able to extract the quantity of the product to show only the numerical value, no alpha text or characters.

The string is:

> [{"orderItemId":609507407,"lineItemKey":"1509870501993","sku":"SKU-111111","name":"Company
>   Product - NA / Ships in 1-2 business
>   days","imageUrl":"https://FAKEADDRESS.com/","weight":{"value":352.0,"units":"ounces","WeightUnits":1},"quantity":1,"unitPrice":1599.0,"taxAmount":null,"shippingAmount":null,"warehouseLocation":null,"options":[],"productId":30236912,"fulfillmentSku":null,"adjustment":false,"upc":"","createDate":"2018-11-03T20:20:42.247","modifyDate":"2018-11-03T20:20:42.247"}]

Using (LEFT(RIGHT(N2:N,LEN(N2:N)-FIND("quantity",N2:N,1)-9),3)) I'm able to find the correct location of the quantity, however, if the numerical value (quantity) is 2 or 3 digits, it will keep whatever text/number follows.

i.e. "quantity":123 will show 123 but "quantity":1," will show 1,"

(LEFT(RIGHT(N2:N,LEN(N2:N)-FIND("quantity",N2:N,1)-9),3))

Essentially, I just want the formula to show a number value (quantity) in the cell. Nothing else.

Comment: I believe with FIND/SEARCH you can specify the starting point.  So find the comma after Quantity,  use that to get your length of characters in the number.

Comment: If you find the end point ie « ,"u » following your start point then you can return the nunber without knowing exactly how many digits it contains...

Comment: Essentially a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432859/4961700

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Text Within a Long Varying String of Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432769/extract-text-within-a-long-varying-string-of-text)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like JSON to me and even Regular Expression may be overkill for a single quantity integer.

```
Dim str As String, el As String, q As Long

str = "[{""orderItemId"":609507407, ... ,""quantity"":1,""unitPrice"":1599.0, ... ,""modifyDate"":""2018-11-03T20:20:42.247""}]"
el = """quantity"":"

q = val(Mid(str, InStr(1, str, el) + Len(el)))
Debug.Print q
```